# Does anyone make a self-driving car?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, building

Mapping and localization are the hottest trends in robotics today. And what's more exciting is they can be both implemented with a low-cost robotics kit like LEGO Mindstorms!

I tried to make a self-driving car, after Google's famous car, but I got stuck on the mechanical side of things. I can't figure out how to build a revolving ultrasonic sensor on top of the robot, in order to do mapping and localization.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you use other methods of ultrasound, like a few ultrasound sensors. A revolving ultrasound is very difficult due to the wire

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to use the Ultrasonic sensor as a revolving radar dish. This is definitely possible. Note that because of the wire, you probably want the sensor to pan back and forth rather than go around in complete circles. Here's an example of what this could look like:

[image: NXT Radar]

There are building instructions for this project available here:

http://www.nxtprograms.com/radar/

Comment: I did build this radar but find it quite limiting. The vertical brick was too long, hence unstable and the wire got twisted around it.
One more thing, it can't be adapted onto a car.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean a full scale car or a LEGO car?